# Can we use bootstrap modal by extracting javascript and css needed for modal and keeping it locally in our code?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

I am new to front end development and I have a requirement of using bootstrap modal.

I tried copying the bootstrap css and js code for modal and kept in my css file and kept the javascript in script tag and tried using the modal. But I am not getting the pop up on clicking button. CSS is getting applied but js part is not working.

Am I missing anything here?

This is bootstrap modal js code -

```
<script type="text/javascript">

'use strict';

// MODAL CLASS DEFINITION
// ======================

var Modal = function (element, options) {
this.options   = options
this.$element  = $(element)
this.$backdrop =
this.isShown   = null

if (this.options.remote) {
this.$element
.find('.modal-content')
.load(this.options.remote, $.proxy(function () {
this.$element.trigger('loaded.bs.modal')
}, this))
}
}

Modal.DEFAULTS = {
backdrop: true,
keyboard: true,
show: true
}

Modal.prototype.toggle = function (_relatedTarget) {
return this[!this.isShown ? 'show' : 'hide'](_relatedTarget)
}

Modal.prototype.show = function (_relatedTarget) {
var that = this
var e    = $.Event('show.bs.modal', { relatedTarget: _relatedTarget })

this.$element.trigger(e)

if (this.isShown || e.isDefaultPrevented()){ return }

this.isShown = true

this.escape()

this.$element.on('click.dismiss.bs.modal', '[data-dismiss="modal"]', $.proxy(this.hide, this))

this.backdrop(function () {
var transition = $.support.transition && that.$element.hasClass('fade')

if (!that.$element.parent().length) {
that.$element.appendTo(document.body) // don't move modals dom position
}

that.$element
.show()
.scrollTop(0)

if (transition) {
that.$element[0].offsetWidth // force reflow
}

that.$element
.addClass('in')
.attr('aria-hidden', false)

that.enforceFocus()

var e = $.Event('shown.bs.modal', { relatedTarget: _relatedTarget })

transition ?
that.$element.find('.modal-dialog') // wait for modal to slide in
.one($.support.transition.end, function () {
that.$element.focus().trigger(e)
})
.emulateTransitionEnd(300) :
that.$element.focus().trigger(e)
})
}

Modal.prototype.hide = function (e) {
if (e) { e.preventDefault() }

e = $.Event('hide.bs.modal')

this.$element.trigger(e)

if (!this.isShown || e.isDefaultPrevented()) { return }

this.isShown = false

this.escape()

$(document).off('focusin.bs.modal')

this.$element
.removeClass('in')
.attr('aria-hidden', true)
.off('click.dismiss.bs.modal')

$.support.transition && this.$element.hasClass('fade') ?
this.$element
.one($.support.transition.end, $.proxy(this.hideModal, this))
.emulateTransitionEnd(300) :
this.hideModal()
}

Modal.prototype.enforceFocus = function () {
$(document)
.off('focusin.bs.modal') // guard against infinite focus loop
.on('focusin.bs.modal', $.proxy(function (e) {
if (this.$element[0] !== e.target && !this.$element.has(e.target).length) {
this.$element.focus()
}
}, this))
}

Modal.prototype.escape = function () {
if (this.isShown && this.options.keyboard) {
this.$element.on('keyup.dismiss.bs.modal', $.proxy(function (e) {
e.which === 27 && this.hide()
}, this))
} else if (!this.isShown) {
this.$element.off('keyup.dismiss.bs.modal')
}
}

Modal.prototype.hideModal = function () {
var that = this
this.$element.hide()
this.backdrop(function () {
that.removeBackdrop()
that.$element.trigger('hidden.bs.modal')
})
}

Modal.prototype.removeBackdrop = function () {
this.$backdrop && this.$backdrop.remove()
this.$backdrop = null
}

Modal.prototype.backdrop = function (callback) {
var animate = this.$element.hasClass('fade') ? 'fade' : ''

if (this.isShown && this.options.backdrop) {
var doAnimate = $.support.transition && animate

this.$backdrop = $('<div class="modal-backdrop ' + animate + '" />')
.appendTo(document.body)

this.$element.on('click.dismiss.bs.modal', $.proxy(function (e) {
if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {return}
this.options.backdrop === 'static' ? this.$element[0].focus.call(this.$element[0]) : this.hide.call(this)
}, this))

if (doAnimate) {this.$backdrop[0].offsetWidth} // force reflow

this.$backdrop.addClass('in')

if (!callback) { return }

doAnimate ?
this.$backdrop
.one($.support.transition.end, callback)
.emulateTransitionEnd(150) :
callback()

} else if (!this.isShown && this.$backdrop) {
this.$backdrop.removeClass('in')

$.support.transition && this.$element.hasClass('fade') ?
this.$backdrop
.one($.support.transition.end, callback)
.emulateTransitionEnd(150) :
callback()

} else if (callback) {
callback()
}
}


// MODAL PLUGIN DEFINITION
// =======================

var old = $.fn.modal

$.fn.modal = function (option, _relatedTarget) {
return this.each(function () {
var $this   = $(this)
var data    = $this.data('bs.modal')
var options = $.extend({}, Modal.DEFAULTS, $this.data(), typeof option === 'object' && option)

if (!data) { $this.data('bs.modal', (data = new Modal(this, options))) }
if (typeof option === 'string') { data[option](_relatedTarget) }
else if (options.show) { data.show(_relatedTarget) }
})
}

$.fn.modal.Constructor = Modal


// MODAL NO CONFLICT
// =================

$.fn.modal.noConflict = function () {
$.fn.modal = old
return this
}


// MODAL DATA-API
// ==============

$(document).on('click.bs.modal.data-api', '[data-toggle="modal"]', function (e) {
var $this   = $(this)
var href    = $this.attr('href')
var $target = $($this.attr('data-target') || (href && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, ''))) //strip for ie7
var option  = $target.data('bs.modal') ? 'toggle' : $.extend({ remote: !/#/.test(href) && href }, $target.data(), $this.data())

if ($this.is('a')) { e.preventDefault() }

$target
.modal(option, this)
.one('hide', function () {
$this.is(':visible') && $this.focus()
})
})

$(document)
.on('show.bs.modal', '.modal', function () { $(document.body).addClass('modal-open') })
.on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () { $(document.body).removeClass('modal-open') })



</script>
```

This is how I am invoking the modal

```
 <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        Open modal
        </button>

        <!-- The Modal -->
            <div class="modal" id="myModal">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">

                <!-- Modal Header -->
                         <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        </div>

                    <!-- Modal body -->
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            Modal body..
                        </div>

                    <!-- Modal footer -->
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: If you need Bootstrap, add Bootstrap to your page, and use it accordingly to the docs. Do not try to import only the part you need out of the sources, especially if you are new to front dev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. Although i am not sure why do you want to do this. Here is your code.

```js
 'use strict';

        // MODAL CLASS DEFINITION
        // ======================

        var Modal = function (element, options) {
            this.options = options
            this.$element = $(element)
            this.$backdrop =
                this.isShown = null

            if (this.options.remote) {
                this.$element
                    .find('.modal-content')
                    .load(this.options.remote, $.proxy(function () {
                        this.$element.trigger('loaded.bs.modal')
                    }, this))
            }
        }

        Modal.DEFAULTS = {
            backdrop: true,
            keyboard: true,
            show: true
        }

        Modal.prototype.toggle = function (_relatedTarget) {
            return this[!this.isShown ? 'show' : 'hide'](_relatedTarget)
        }

        Modal.prototype.show = function (_relatedTarget) {
            var that = this
            var e = $.Event('show.bs.modal', {
                relatedTarget: _relatedTarget
            })

            this.$element.trigger(e)

            if (this.isShown || e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
                return
            }

            this.isShown = true

            this.escape()

            this.$element.on('click.dismiss.bs.modal', '[data-dismiss="modal"]', $.proxy(this.hide, this))

            this.backdrop(function () {
                var transition = $.support.transition && that.$element.hasClass('fade')

                if (!that.$element.parent().length) {
                    that.$element.appendTo(document.body) // don't move modals dom position
                }

                that.$element
                    .show()
                    .scrollTop(0)

                if (transition) {
                    that.$element[0].offsetWidth // force reflow
                }

                that.$element
                    .addClass('in')
                    .attr('aria-hidden', false)

                that.enforceFocus()

                var e = $.Event('shown.bs.modal', {
                    relatedTarget: _relatedTarget
                })

                transition ?
                    that.$element.find('.modal-dialog') // wait for modal to slide in
                    .one($.support.transition.end, function () {
                        that.$element.focus().trigger(e)
                    })
                    .emulateTransitionEnd(300) :
                    that.$element.focus().trigger(e)
            })
        }

        Modal.prototype.hide = function (e) {
            if (e) {
                e.preventDefault()
            }

            e = $.Event('hide.bs.modal')

            this.$element.trigger(e)

            if (!this.isShown || e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
                return
            }

            this.isShown = false

            this.escape()

            $(document).off('focusin.bs.modal')

            this.$element
                .removeClass('in')
                .attr('aria-hidden', true)
                .off('click.dismiss.bs.modal')

            $.support.transition && this.$element.hasClass('fade') ?
                this.$element
                .one($.support.transition.end, $.proxy(this.hideModal, this))
                .emulateTransitionEnd(300) :
                this.hideModal()
        }

        Modal.prototype.enforceFocus = function () {
            $(document)
                .off('focusin.bs.modal') // guard against infinite focus loop
                .on('focusin.bs.modal', $.proxy(function (e) {
                    if (this.$element[0] !== e.target && !this.$element.has(e.target).length) {
                        this.$element.focus()
                    }
                }, this))
        }

        Modal.prototype.escape = function () {
            if (this.isShown && this.options.keyboard) {
                this.$element.on('keyup.dismiss.bs.modal', $.proxy(function (e) {
                    e.which === 27 && this.hide()
                }, this))
            } else if (!this.isShown) {
                this.$element.off('keyup.dismiss.bs.modal')
            }
        }

        Modal.prototype.hideModal = function () {
            var that = this
            this.$element.hide()
            this.backdrop(function () {
                that.removeBackdrop()
                that.$element.trigger('hidden.bs.modal')
            })
        }

        Modal.prototype.removeBackdrop = function () {
            this.$backdrop && this.$backdrop.remove()
            this.$backdrop = null
        }

        Modal.prototype.backdrop = function (callback) {
            var animate = this.$element.hasClass('fade') ? 'fade' : ''

            if (this.isShown && this.options.backdrop) {
                var doAnimate = $.support.transition && animate

                this.$backdrop = $('<div class="modal-backdrop ' + animate + '" />')
                    .appendTo(document.body)

                this.$element.on('click.dismiss.bs.modal', $.proxy(function (e) {
                    if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
                        return
                    }
                    this.options.backdrop === 'static' ? this.$element[0].focus.call(this.$element[0]) :
                        this.hide.call(this)
                }, this))

                if (doAnimate) {
                    this.$backdrop[0].offsetWidth
                } // force reflow

                this.$backdrop.addClass('in')

                if (!callback) {
                    return
                }

                doAnimate ?
                    this.$backdrop
                    .one($.support.transition.end, callback)
                    .emulateTransitionEnd(150) :
                    callback()

            } else if (!this.isShown && this.$backdrop) {
                this.$backdrop.removeClass('in')

                $.support.transition && this.$element.hasClass('fade') ?
                    this.$backdrop
                    .one($.support.transition.end, callback)
                    .emulateTransitionEnd(150) :
                    callback()

            } else if (callback) {
                callback()
            }
        }


        // MODAL PLUGIN DEFINITION
        // =======================

        var old = $.fn.modal

        $.fn.modal = function (option, _relatedTarget) {
            return this.each(function () {
                var $this = $(this)
                var data = $this.data('bs.modal')
                var options = $.extend({}, Modal.DEFAULTS, $this.data(), typeof option === 'object' &&
                    option)

                if (!data) {
                    $this.data('bs.modal', (data = new Modal(this, options)))
                }
                if (typeof option === 'string') {
                    data[option](_relatedTarget)
                } else if (options.show) {
                    data.show(_relatedTarget)
                }
            })
        }

        $.fn.modal.Constructor = Modal


        // MODAL NO CONFLICT
        // =================

        $.fn.modal.noConflict = function () {
            $.fn.modal = old
            return this
        }


        // MODAL DATA-API
        // ==============

        $(document).on('click.bs.modal.data-api', '[data-toggle="modal"]', function (e) {
            var $this = $(this)
            var href = $this.attr('href')
            var $target = $($this.attr('data-target') || (href && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, ''))) //strip for ie7
            var option = $target.data('bs.modal') ? 'toggle' : $.extend({
                remote: !/#/.test(href) && href
            }, $target.data(), $this.data())

            if ($this.is('a')) {
                e.preventDefault()
            }

            $target
                .modal(option, this)
                .one('hide', function () {
                    $this.is(':visible') && $this.focus()
                })
        })

        $(document)
            .on('body', '.modal', function () {
                $(document.body).addClass('modal-open')
            })
            .on('body', '.modal', function () {
                $(document.body).removeClass('modal-open')
            })
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        Open modal
    </button>

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div class="modal" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">

                <!-- Modal Header -->
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>

                <!-- Modal body -->
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Modal body..
                </div>

                <!-- Modal footer -->
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: yeah jquery is missing and its working once i included that

Comment: @Satyaaditya Great, Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

If you want someone see your code,
you better add your code in jsfiddle.

If you beginner, I prefer you to import library for using modal in bootstrap.

One example website if you want learn and call library through online (copy n paste)

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

If you want local download. You can go

http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2016/07/25/bootstrap-3-3-7-released/

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling function to open the model.
Call `$target.modal("show")` method like below and manage accroding the need.

```
$target.modal(option, this).one('hide', function () {
    $this.is(':visible') && $this.focus()
});
$target.modal("show");
```